# How can I tell which module will execute first?

Tags: javascript

ModuleA imports from ModuleB. And ModuleB imports from ModuleA. Both modules are loaded from the same folder into one `.html` file.

What is the rule that determines which one gets executed first here?

The module below the other one (in source-order) actually seems to get executed first. This seems strange considering I recall reading somewhere that the order modules are executed in is (partly) determined by source-order.

---

```
  <script type="module" src="../js/moduleB.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="../js/moduleA.js"></script>
```

Comment: It depends on the entry point: are you loading ModuleA or ModuleB from elsewhere (first)?

Comment: @Bergi Both modules are loaded from the same folder into one .html file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @tonitone120 How are you loading the modules into the one HTML file?

Comment: @tonitone120 No - which of the two modules is loaded *first* by that html file?

Comment: @Bergi ModuleA script tag is before moduleB script tag if that’s what you mean?

Comment: @Bergi Have added the script tag code to the bottom of the question

Comment: @Pablo Hope my code at the bottom of my question has shown you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the information you are providing it makes sense that ModuleA is been executed first. Your second script tag importing ModuleA is actually redundant. Since you mentioned ModuleB imports ModuleA, ModuleA is executed first because all module imports are processed first. Assuming they are at the top of your script. This is more or less the order of execution.

1. The script tag for `../js/moduleB.js` is loaded.
2. The imports for `moduleB.js` are loaded and proceed. This includes ModuleA.
3. The rest of the code for ModuleB is executed.